# Get MethodInfo of String.TrimStart with reflection?

Tags: c#, string, reflection, startswith, methodinfo

I gonna get `MethodInfo` of `String.TrimStart()`
The following code returns null.

```
typeof(string).GetMethod("TrimStart", new Type[ ] {});
```

and the following code returns `{System.String TrimStart(Char[])}`

```
typeof(string).GetMethod("TrimStart", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

I wanna get `{System.String TrimStart()}` exactly ?

Comment: `TrimStart(Char[])` is the only available method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart

Comment: Didn't you ask something similar before or do I have a deja vu?

Comment: But we can use `TrimStart()` like `"  Mohammad".TrimStart()`

Comment: Another question: Why would you want to invoke a known method.

Comment: I wanna create an entity framework expression, so I need to use reflection to get TrimStart

Comment: Then you going about it in the wrong way.

Comment: So, what's the correct way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `String.TrimStart()` method.

There is only `String.TrimStart(params Char[] source)` overload. You can invoke it without any paramteres thanks to `params` keyword.

In other words: `String.TrimStart()` "invokes" `String.TrimStart(new char[0])`.

More: [params keyword on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)

Comment: Could you please post ot link to how call `TrimStart` with expression?

Comment: Here is link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323922(v=vs.110).aspx First arg is `MethodInfo`. Collection of `Expression` in the second argument should hold one item - expression, that after compile returns `char[]`. It could be `Expression.Constant(new char[0])`.